# Implementing each() for multiple slideshows on the same page

Tags: jquery

It's a slideshow using images in the divs 'store_images'.
Several slideshows on the same page: click on image for next slide, after last image goes to the first. It works if I have just one but I have to implement the each() condition in the second part since they're more, and I have no idea how.

```
$(function(){
    $('.store_images').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.store_book_image:gt(0)').hide(); 
});

$(this).find('img').click(function () {
    $('.store_images :first-child').hide()
       .next('img').show()
       .end().appendTo('.store_images');
}); });
```

Thank you,

Update: HTML

```
<div style="cursor:e-resize;" class="store_images">
                <img class="store_book_image" src="{{ book.image1.url }}" />
                <img class="store_book_image" src="{{ book.image2.url }}" />
                <img class="store_book_image" src="{{ book.image3.url }}" />
                <img class="store_book_image" src="{{ book.image4.url }}" />
</div>
```

Comment: HTML, CSS please. It would be nice to have a *"picture"* of the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$(this).find('img').click(function () {
    var $parentDiv = $(this).closest('.store_images');
    $(':first-child',$parentDiv).hide()
       .next('img').show()
       .end().appendTo($parentDiv);
});
```

That is, on click of a particular img element find the 'store_images' div that it belongs to rather than selecting all 'store_images' divs.

By the way, why `$(this).find('img')` and not `$('img')`? I assume at that point `this` is `document`.

Comment: It works, thank you. Should I also modify the first function (the one who hides all images but the first) or I can leave it like that?

Comment: The first part is supposed to process all of the divs, so you can leave it as is.